# Loading NSData into WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an NSData object and I want to display it in a WebView. Can WebView handle/display `NSData` objects?

```
NSData *data = ... // some data I've gotten from NSURLConnection
WebView *webView = ... [[WebView alloc] init];
```

Comment: What does the `NSData` describe? UTF-8 text? A PNG? Something else?

Comment: It's variable. I allow the user to input a URL, I download it into a NSData object, and then I want to display it depending on what the response headers of the request were.

Comment: Unless you've created a custom data format, an `NSData` no longer has the request headers. It's just the body. Give the URL to the view directly.

Comment: I have the headers of the request/response stored elsewhere.

Comment: I need to capture these to display elsewhere in the app. It seems wasteful to pass the URL I've already fetched to WebView to do yet another request.

Comment: Yeah. Don't do the request. Let web view do the request. Otherwise you'll probably have to implement a custom URL scheme for web view to access.

Comment: So your question is, how to write a do-anything view controller.  (Or, better yet, where to copy one from.)

Comment: @HotLicks That's not at all what my question is; My question in fact is pretty specific. Can WebView handle/display NSData

Comment: @Tommy You suggestion, whether I do the second request, or allow WebView to do it would result in TWO duplicate requests. What if the request was a POST (or anything besides a GET really)? That would be very bad.

Comment: @kyledecot no it wouldn't. My words were "Don't do the request". You're saying "if I do a request, and web view does a request, then that makes two requests". So don't do a request. Just let the web view do the request.

Comment: ... if you're asking "can web view magically reconstruct HTTP headers when I've thrown them away?" then the answer is no.

Comment: @Tommy Nobody is asking to magically recreate the headers. As stated, I *saved* them elsewhere. I need to do the initial request using `NSURLConnection` in order to obtain information (headers, request time, redirects, etc) that I can't do by simply passing the `NSURL` to `WebView`. If the solution was to simply display a URL in a WebView then of course this would work. However this is *not* what I asked; I asked if WebView objects could handle/display NSData. If the answer is NO then that's fine but please provide snarky comments.

Comment: @kyledecot you can see my serious, non-snarky attempt to answer your question below. It was posted about four minutes before your comment.

Comment: Again, I have the headers. I stated that VERY clearly (multiple times).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62716/discussion-between-kyledecot-and-tommy).

Answer (score 2):

Yes! 
NSData is handled by UIWebView when properly supplied with MIME type.
This snippet loads a .docx file in a WebView

```
NSString *path = [urlFileInView path];
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];


webViewForDocsView.delegate = self;
[webViewForDocsView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using `WebView`, not `UIWebView`

Answer (score 0):

Without the Content-Type header, the web view has no way to know how to interpret the data. That's why the Content-Type header was added.

If for some reason you want an `NSData` capture of network traffic that you can replay whenever you want, consider writing a custom [`NSURLProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you write a handler for `http` then it will override the built-in one; give it a fall-through memory and it can redirect those requests to the real one.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 [self.webView loadHTMLString: newStr baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the data may not be HTML (and may not be UTF-8, but that's unlikely).